# OPENCV error while captureing video from webcam in python

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I've been struggling for a while trying to access the webcam of my laptop (MSI GS65 stealth) through opencv-python.
I've tried with python 3.9 and python 3.10, with opencv-python 4.5.3.56 and 4.6.0.66

The minimum amount of code that reproduces the error in my computer.

```
import cv2

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while (capture.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    cv2.imshow('webCam',frame)
    if (cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('s')):
        break

capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Running from the console, using PyCharm with a virtual environment (or the windows Command prompt), the camera activates (a red light turns on besides the camera for a few seconds) but no window is opened and I get this error:

```
[ WARN:0@12.618] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (1752) CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147483638
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\OneDrive - CINVESTAV\Python\RHEED app\video_test.py", line 7, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('webCam',frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:967: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

The strange thing is that running from the IPython console through `runfile('video_test.py')` appears to be working just fine, a window pops with the images captured by the camera, and closes when I click 's'. Also, a few days ago it was working fine, then stopped working. I even made a fresh Windows 10 install, it worked yesterday even from the console, but today it's broken again.

Comment: Check the variable `ret`, does it return `True`? And what is the purpose of `cv2.CAP_DVSHOW`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo I left trying to change backends to make it work, but it didn't. I edited the code. 
ret returns False if I run it from the terminal and True if I use the IPython console.

Comment: -2147483638 is 0x8000000A, which is E_PENDING.  Does your camera work in normal camera applications?  Can you use it with vlc?

Comment: try: https://webcamtests.com/resolution

Comment: @TimRoberts, I tried using it with VLC and it works. However, I also tried an app for capturing video and taking pictures from a microscope celestron camera (https://www.celestron.com/) and that is also not working. It detects de camera but I can't use it. A few weeks ago I used it and it worked normally.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I looks like input is 0x0 picture, thats why i cannot show, if you know your camera resolution try this maybe:

```
camera=0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1050)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920)

while cap.isOpened():
    success, image = cap.read()
    if not success:
      print("Ignoring empty camera frame.")
      # If loading a video, use 'break' instead of 'continue'.
      continue
    cv2.imshow('Image', image)
    if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
      break
cap.release()
```

good luck

Comment: I have tried this before. The webcam is 640x480. Sadly all I get is black window. Still responsive though, can close it with `q` with no troubles.

Comment: I think I might have found the solution. It was a bit trivial. But it was actually the antivirus blocking the access to the camera through opencv. I disabled it and it worked! I still needed to change the backend to DSHOW, but it finally works!.

Comment: Well gratz, i think i will remove this bad answer then, since i m reciving bad karma for it...gratz :D